# Расстояние до маркеров списком из google maps

Tags: xcode, google-maps-api, ios, objective-c

Использую для расстановки маркеров на карте вот такой код:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.957069, 30.323013);
GMSMarker *london2 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position2];
london2.title = @"Офис";
london2.snippet = @"Центральный офис";
london2.map = mapView_;
```

Увидел приложение втб и очень хочу сделать так же, т.е. чтобы в одной view была карта, а во второй список саркеров и расстояние до них. Как мне вывести список маркеров и расстояние до них?

Пример того, что хочу:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
CLLocationDistance kilometers = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:officeCoordinate];
```